# Why are Swift's UnsafePointer and UnsafeBufferPointer not interchangeable?

Tags: swift, unsafe-pointers

I've been working quite a bit with Apple's neural net tools, which means I've been working quite a bit with unsafe pointers. I grew up with C, and I've been working with Swift for quite a while, so I'm comfortable using them, but there's one thing about them that has me totally stumped.

I can't figure out why there's any effort involved in deriving one kind of unsafe pointer from another. In general, it seems like it should be trivial, but the initializers for the different types are specific about what kind of input they'll take, and I'm having a hard time figuring out  the rules.

An easy and specific example, perhaps the one that stumps me the most

```
// The neural net components want mutable raw memory, and it's easier
// to build them up from the bottom, so: raw memory
let floats = 100
let bytes = floats * MemoryLayout<Float>.size

let raw = UnsafeMutableRawPointer.allocate(byteCount: bytes, alignment: MemoryLayout<Float>.alignment)

// Higher up in the app, I want to use memory that just looks like an array
// of Floats, to minimize the ugly unsafe stuff everywhere. So I'll use
// a buffer pointer, and that's where the first confusing thing shows up:

// This won't work
// let inputs = UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<Float>(start: raw, count: floats)

// The initializer won't take raw memory. But it will take a plain old
// UnsafePointer<Float>. Where to get that? you can get it from the raw pointer
let unsafeMutablePointer = raw.bindMemory(to: Float.self, capacity: floats)

// Buf if that's possible, then why wouldn't there be a buffer pointer initializer for it?

// Of course, with the plain old pointer, I can get my buffer pointer
let inputs = UnsafeMutableBufferPointer(start: unsafeMutablePointer, count: floats)
```

Although I haven't been able to find any discussion of the theory behind the different kinds, I did find a clue in [this tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/7181017-unsafe-swift-using-pointers-and-interacting-with-c). There's a diagram comparing the different types, which says that plain old `UnsafePointer` is strideable but not a collection, while `UnsafeBufferPointer` is a collection but isn't strideable.

I understand the concept of a collection that isn't strideable, like a set. But these two types of unsafe pointers allow subscripts. They work just like regular arrays, which sounds to me like they're both strideable collections. Perhaps there's a subtle clue in there that I'm missing.

Why is it not possible to get an `UnsafeBufferPointer` from a type that you can get an `UnsafePointer` from?

Comment: "then why wouldn't there be a buffer pointer initializer for it?' That's a design decision that only the designers can tell you why. In any case, you could just start with `UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>.allocate`, rather than `UnsafeMutableRawPointer.allocate`, couldn't you?

Comment: Also, I'm a bit concerned about how you call `bindMemory`. `capacity` is the number of instances of `Float` that you want to bind, not the number of bytes. So you should probably pass `100 / MemoryLayout<Float>.size` instead.

Comment: Also note that you can turn a `UnsafeMutableRawPointer` to a `UnsafeRawBufferPointer` directly. It seems like the design here is that if you have a raw pointer, you can either 1) make it not raw, or 2) make it a buffer, If you want to do both things, you need two steps.

Comment: Good catch on the size of the buffers, thanks much

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The distinction between these types isn't quite as large as you might imagine. Conceptually, `UnsafeBufferPointer` can be viewed as a tuple of `(UnsafePointer, Int)`, i.e., a pointer to a buffer of elements in memory with a known count. `UnsafePointer`, in contrast, is a pointer to an element in memory with an *unknown* count; `UnsafePointer` more closely represents what you might be used to as an arbitrary pointer in C: it may point to a single element, or to the start of a contiguous grouping of several elements, but on its own, there's no way to find out.

`UnsafeBufferPointer` having a known count also means that it is *able* to conform to `Collection` (which requires a known start and end) as opposed to `UnsafePointer`, which doesn't have that information.

Swift is very much a language of semantics, and places great emphasis on expressing in the type system knowledge about the tools you have available to you. As you point out, there are operations you can perform on one type and not another — this is by design, to make some operations more difficult to perform incorrectly.

These pointers are convertible, too:

- `UnsafeBufferPointer` has a `baseAddress` which *is* an `UnsafePointer`: given a buffer, you can always "throw away" information about the count to get the underlying uncounted pointer
- Given an `UnsafePointer` and a `count`, you can also express the existence of a buffer in memory with [`UnsafeBufferPointer.init(start:count:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/unsafebufferpointer/1538692-init)

The general answer is: use the most specific pointer type that you can to represent the data that you have. It is usually preferred to that you use the `Buffer` variants of pointers if you're pointing to more than one element, and know how many you have. Similarly, if you're pointing to arbitrary bytes in memory (which may or may not have a type), you should use `Raw` pointers if possible. (And, of course, if you need to write to these locations in memory, you'll need to use the `Mutable` variants of those too.)

For more information, I highly recommend Andrew Trick's talk from WWDC 2020 about this subject: [Safely manage pointers in Swift](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10167/). He goes into great detail about the conceptual state machine representing the lifetimes of pointers in Swift, and how to convert between and use the pointer types correctly. (It's as close to the horse's mouth as you can get when on the topic.)

---

Separately, about your example code: @Sweeper correctly points out in a comment that if you're looking to allocate a buffer of `Float`s, you shouldn't allocate a raw buffer and bind its memory type. In general, allocating raw buffers not only runs the risk of mistaking the size of the buffer needed, but also risks not taking into account padding (which would have to be calculated manually for some types).

Instead, you *should* use [`UnsafeMutableBufferPointer.allocate(capacity:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/unsafemutablebufferpointer/2949512-allocate) to allocate the buffer, which you can then write to. It correctly takes into account alignment and padding, so you can't get it wrong.

The difference between raw memory and typed memory is very subtle in Swift, and Andy describes it much better in the linked talk than I can here, but tl;dr: raw memory is a collection of untyped bytes which could represent anything, whereas typed memory represents *only* values of a specific type (and cannot be safely reinterpreted arbitrarly, save for a few exceptions, a major departure from C!); you should almost *never* have to bind memory manually, and if you bind memory to non-trivial types, you're almost *certainly* doing it wrong. (Not that you're doing that here, but just a heads-up)

---

Finally, on the subject of `Strideable` vs. `Collection`, and subscripting — the fact that you can subscript into both matches the behavior of C, but has a subtle *semantic* distinction in Swift.

Subscripting into an `UnsafePointer` means largely what it does in C: an `UnsafePointer` knows its base type, and referencing a single location in memory, can calculate where the next object of that type in memory would be using the type's alignment and padding (this is what its `Strideable` conformance implies); subscripting allows you to access one of several contiguous objects in memory relative to the one the pointer refers to. Also, just like in C: because you don't know where a group of such objects ends, you can subscript arbitrarily using an `UnsafePointer` with no bounds checks — there simply wouldn't be any way to know whether an access you're trying to make is valid ahead of time.

On the other hand, subscripting through `UnsafeBufferPointer` is like accessing an element *inside* of a collection of elements in memory. Because there are clear bounds on where the buffer starts and ends, you get bounds checking, and indexing out of bounds on an `UnsafeBufferPointer` is much more clearly an error. Along those lines, a `Strideable` conformance on `UnsafeBufferPointer` wouldn't make much sense: the "stride" of a `Strideable` type indicates that it knows how to get to the "next" one, but there isn't a logical "next" buffer after an entire `UnsafeBufferPointer`.

So both of these types end up with a subscript operator that *effectively* performs the same operation, but semantically has a very different meaning.

Comment: This helps a lot, thank you. I'm glad you mentioned `Strideable` and `UnsafeBufferPointer`. That explains so many things, cheers

Comment: I just have to tell you, Itai, that I have come back numerous times to re-read your answer; you've shined an incredibly bright light on part of Swift that's always seemed a bit shadowy. Cheers

Comment: @SaganRitual Thank you very much for the kind words. :) It's truly a pleasure to help untangle tricky topics like this and try to do so as best I can. Appreciated!